# How to test Sequelize migrations?

Tags: testing, migration, sequelize.js

Is it necessary to cover `Sequelize` migrations with unit tests, or even functional tests to check how they affect DB structure? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho testing migrations is not necessary. Neither for sequelize nor any other decent ORM.

1. Migrations describe how your database must be altered to become compliant with the current state of the application that uses it. In a sense they are therefore not part of the application itself. Therefore no testing required.
2. Migrations typically don't implement any custom logic. They just call a bunch of methods of the migration library. And the library used should itself be thoroughly unit tested. Therefore no additional testing required.

Comment: But what if you made a mistake, especially with data migration.. isn't it a good approach to run the migration and then check if the changes are applied to the target DB?

Comment: Of course it's a good idea to check wether your migration does what it should do. Especially its a good idea to check it before you run it in production. Just like any other config change. But its probably not something you want periodically re-check in an automated test suite.

Comment: I just wonder why not? because it's very sensitive part in the application that no one really checks - just manually, so thought maybe there is some techniques to do it.

Comment: Because I don't consider it as "part of the application". It's a part of the history how your application evolved. But if your keen to test migrations, write a test that runs your migrations step by step and after each add some assertions that check your database schema.